# Segmentation fault in Pybind11 when trying to bridge yices library in usr/local/include

Tags: c++, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pybind11

I am trying to bridge my c++ code with python using pybind11. I have example.cpp file and it has an include to yices.h. yices.h is in usr/local/includes folder.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "yices.h"   

int add(int i, int j) {
    yices_init();
    return i + j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

    // define add function
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
 }
```

When I try the test.py I am getting a segmentation error. How to link yices.h using pybind11?

```
from example import add
```

Here is the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(example)

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)
```

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://github.com/SRI-CSL/yices2 ?

Comment: Yes. I am using this API:https://yices.csl.sri.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to link it with `gmp` and `yices`:

```
target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC yices gmp)
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you very much. Can you please explain why I need to link it with gmp

Comment: No worries! When I built your example I got an error during import time that module has undefined `gmp` symbols. That's why I linked with `gmp`. `yices` uses `gmp`. `gmp` is one of its prerequisites.

Comment: Hi there is another issue. i have used an API iverilog. The path is not in "/usr/local/bin". How to link this? The path for the iverilog is something like this - /home/download/iverilog

Comment: You can use `target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC full_path_to_library)`

Comment: I tried that. But I am getting this error - /usr/bin/ld: /home/hasini/Downloads/iverilog/bin/iverilog: stdout: invalid version 4 (max 0)

Comment: Are you sure you are linking with a library? To me `bin/iverilog` seems like an executable. Besides, I think you should look in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library